Wordpress reset the post back after a loop
I have this loop here to get my blog posts:
<div class="row">
    <?php query_posts( 'post_type=post&posts_per_page=3'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-right">
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
        <div style="background:url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>'); background-size:cover; background-position:center; height:250px;"></div>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button">Read More</a>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

Which is working well, but anything after this loop does not work, for an example I am using Advance Custom Fields and here is what I got after the loop
<section id="action" style="background: url(<?php echo wp_kses_post(get_field('call_to_action_background')); ?>); background-position: center; background-size: cover;">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 data-aos="fade-down"><?php echo wp_kses_post(get_field('call_to_action_title')); ?></h2>
                <a data-aos="fade-up" href="#" class="button">Get Started</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

This was working before I added the loop, but it didn't work and by not working I mean the my background url is empty and my h2 is also empty.

get_field is used to pull a field from a specific post, so I'm not certain how you have both a single post as well as a loop, unless the loop is a custom loop?

Oh wait, I see the query_posts now. Check out this chart, basically avoid that function in favor of pretty much anything else: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/12496. My personal preference is to always use get_posts because there's no loop ever

It is a custom loop...i'll post my whole code

That did not work for me, I added remove_all_filters before and after query_posts

@user979331, did you see my note about not using query_posts? That is meant for the main query only really, not custom queries. The docs even say "This function will completely override the main query and isn’t intended for use by plugins or themes. Its overly-simplistic approach to modifying the main query can be problematic and should be avoided wherever possible." Checkout out either new WP_Query or get_posts(). The former still needs a resets usually, while the latter never does.

I changed it to new WP_Query (i'll update my question, but still ID of the post outside the loop aftwards is the same ID as the last post in the loop

When using a WP_Query you'll need to call wp_reset_postdata() at the end
